# using ng-class to toggle class

Tags: css, angularjs, ng-class

I have a function called isApplication that does a validation on if a certain application is true or false. I want it to display a different bootstrap class depending on the results of the function

I want to use this function to determine which class gets printed on a certain div....for example

html:

```
<div ng-class="{'col-md-6':isApplication, 'col-md-3':!isApplication}"></div>
```

it doesnt seem to be working like the way i want it to...am i not using ng-class right?

Comment: Have you tried calling the function?  `{ myclass: myFunction() }`

Comment: @ChrisFarmer - yes that can be done , but if there are more classes and complex logic then should go for that option

Answer (score 2, accepted):

can you try like this , make use of ternary operator

```
ng-class="isApplication ? 'col-md-6' : 'col-md-3'">
```